# R Shiny: Get DT row background color on top of column background color

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, dt

I am using `DT::renderDT` in a shiny app and am formatting background color for certain columns and rows. I need the row background color to be on top of column background color. I tried switching order of `formatStyle` but that didn't work. Here's a small example -

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {    
    output$table <- renderDT({
      head(iris) %>%
        datatable() %>%
        formatStyle(c(2,4), backgroundColor = "#fcf4d9") %>%
        formatStyle(1, target = 'row', 
          backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(4.7, 5), c("#fc8a8a", "#fc8a8a"))
          # comment above row and ucomment below row for row color using styleInterval()
          # backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0, 5, 9), c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange'))

        )
    })
  }
)
```

Result (incorrect) with `styleEqual()` -

[image: Example with styleEqual]

Result (incorrect) with `StyleInterval()` -

[image: Example with styleInterval]

> **The row colors need to be on top of yellow (column color).**

Looking for a generalized solution that would work for multiple rows and with `styleEqual()` or `styleInterval()`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, displayNum, displayIndex, dataIndex){",
  "  if(data[1] === 4.7){",
  "    $(row).find('td').addClass('red');",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          "table.dataTable tbody tr td.red {background-color: #fc8a8a !important}"
        )
      )
    ),
    DTOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {    
    output$table <- renderDT({
      head(iris) %>%
        datatable(options = list(rowCallback = JS(rowCallback))) %>%
        formatStyle(c(2,4), backgroundColor = "#fcf4d9")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the solution. I couldn't generalize it for cases where I have more than one row to color (I am no good with JS). I updated the question accordingly. Would be great if you can include some explanation on how to generalize in your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Shree That's not clear to me. Could you give an example for multiple rows, including a `styleInterval` ?

Comment: Hey, my example shows 2 rows `Sepal.Length = c(4.7, 5)` colored red using `styleEqual()`. Also updated the example to include `styleInterval()`. Let me know if it's still not clear. Thanks!

Comment: For the `styleEqual(4.7,5)` just replace `if(data[1] === 4.7)` with `if(data[1] === 4.7 || data[1] === 5)`.

Comment: @Shree I don't see what you expect with `styleInterval`: this will add a background color to *every* row, so if this background is on top, the background for the columns will be invisible.

Comment: Yes, your point about `styleInterval()` does make sense. I was only focusing on the code and didn't think of that. Also your solution for `styleEqual(4.7, 5)` is good for now. Thanks for the help!